# Yii2 access the Joined table column

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I am new to Yii2 and I am wondering how to access the values of a relational table in ActiveRecord

for Instance we have these 2 Models:

Supplier Has Many Product

Product Has One Supplier

```
class Supplier extends ActiveRecord{

        public function getProducts(){
            return $this->hasMany(Product::className(),["supplier_id"=>"id"]);
        }
        public static function tableName(){
            return 'supplier';
        }
    }

class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getSupplier(){
        return $this->hasOne(Supplier::className(),['id'=>'supplier_id']);
    }
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }
}
```

To Access the Product data I use this line of code

```
$product=Product::find()->joinWith('supplier')->all();
var_dump($product);
```

This Code gives me Correctly the data of Product table but I can't access the Supplier data value, why ? How to Access the value of joined Table ?

Comment: `$product->supplier` related data.

Comment: @ineersa tried it supplier is private

Comment: Ofcourse it's private and also in array. When you write `$product->supplier` and this attribute doesn't exist `__get()` method of base model will call `getSupplier()` method. That's how such things (some kind of getters) in Yii work.

Comment: @ineersa I tried what you told $product->supplier This is the error I am receiving:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It says `$product` is `null` or not `activeRecord` object. Try  `asArray()` and dump it. Also try without `joinWith()`.

Comment: $pr=Product::find()->joinWith('supplier')->all();
            var_dump($pr->supplier);

Comment: @ineersa maybe I should mention That I am calling it from a Controller that is extending from ActiveController

Comment: @ineersa like this  Product::find()->joinWith('supplier')->asArray()?

Comment: `find()->asArray()->all()` will return records in array.

Comment: Still the Same  $pr=Product::find()->asArray()->all();
            var_dump($pr->supplier);

Comment: @ineersa in fact you solved my problem I should have called it that way Product::find()->joinWith("supplier")->asArray()->all(); Thank you very much

Comment: @ineersa you can write the solution so I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access join data then use [asArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#asArray()-detail):

```
Product::find()->joinWith("supplier")->asArray()->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the supplier data through joinWith use the following

```
$product=Product::find()->joinWith('supplier')->all();
```

it will return array if you want to access the supplier data then use the following

```
$product[0]->supplier
```

it will return the supplier modal, you can now access any attribute like

```
$product[0]->supplier->name
```